# Where I can find location id of location when using Instagram API

Tags: ios, api, swift, instagram

I want to use Instagram API to get a list of recent media objects from a given location. 
I am using this URL.
Now I can't do that, because I don't know where I should take location id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.
First use `facebook graph API` to search locations and get `facebook_places_id`. Here is an example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=&type=place&center=37.77493,-122.419415&distance=5000&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&expires_in=5184000
```

2.
Get the `facebook_places_id` and use this `instagram location search API` to get the corresponding `instagram_location_id`

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?facebook_places_id=273471170716&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

3.
Get the location `id` and then make the `instagram location media API` to get recent media:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/514276/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Here is an implementation of Instagram location media search using the above method: **http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/places**

Comment: Thanks for answer. What if I will use Google maps Api? Is it better? @krisrak

Comment: google maps API will not help in getting location id, you can use it to map the locations after u get using the above steps

Answer (score 6):

If you can obtain the Latitude and Longitude of the location, you can use the following code to find images from that specific location:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```