# How to implement instagrams location search

Tags: objective-c, ios7, instagram, core-location

Please point me to the right directions, I want to implement this on my app:

http://tinypic.com/r/2e6gger/8

The image above came from instagram app after tapping on Add to Photo Map option, 3rd page when adding a new image.

From what I understand so far, core location can give me the exact position of the device but not 
the other locations I see on the page above as suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are searching for https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests. Using place search, you can find 20 result at a time. You have to pass latitude, longitude, radius. Enjoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we decided to use foursquare's api.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those location names come from facebook places, you have call the facebook graph API for places and then find the corresponding instagram location id, here is related question with the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26685713/423089